# Webview resource listener not catching loaded resources

Tags: java, android, webview

I have a webview application that listens to clicks and compares them to predefined strings to check if I need to hook into my Java.

I started with the obvious:

```
shouldOverrideUrlLoading
```

and in there do something along the lines of:

```
if(url.contains(myhook)){
   //do what i need 
}
```

This is fine for when its dealing with user clicks in the webview.  But now I'm at the point where I need to catch if a resource loads a url.  So I found 'onLoadResource' and figured this is what I want - but I cannot get it working.

My general setup:

```
private String myhook = "http://domain.com/listener";
{ ... }
@Override
public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url)
    {
    if(url.contains(myhook)){

        //do my stuff!!

        mWebView.loadUrl("http://domain.com/success.html");
    }
    else
    {
        super.onLoadResource(view, url);
    }           
}
```

My web code (index.html):

```
{...}
<a href="http://domain.com/processing.php" >sign up</a>
{...}
```

That calls my php processing page:

```
<?php
{...}
header('Location: http://domain.com/listener/?data=#data#');
?>
```

But my hook never gets invoked so success.html never gets loaded and my "do my stuff" never happens.  It tries to send the request to http://domain.com/listener/?data=#data# which doesn't exist (I'm just using that to grab #data#).

One thing to note is that my "onLoadResource" is inside my `private class TestWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {` right before my `@Override public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading` - not sure if this is correct.

Any help or other methods would be appreciated.

Comment: An fyi to anyone else with this problem: I could get the above method working (ie having onLoadResource catch my hook) when a user clicked a link, then went to a processing page and got forwarded to my hook.  But heres the catch, it doesn't work if the processing page gets initiated from a form submit (this had me stumped for days).  So I did a little javascript function and instead of using a form submit I made it an <a>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `onLoadResource()` will not trigger, neither do `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` will trigger in this case, this is a bit disappointing but I found that in a WebView, all those requests within a html page is not triggered (like Images, CSS and so on). You have two options:

1. Inject Javascript in that html that *knows* how to communicate with Android Java. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setJavaScriptEnabled(boolean)
2. Pre-process your html page and replace all those parts that request the resource you need with something you desired.

I once made a RSS reader which needs Caching images. I use the (2) approach and replace all `img` sources to local resource. It works but quite some heavy works though. At that time I just use Simple Regex to do the replacement but alternatively you can use library like [HTMLTidy](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftidy.sourceforge.net%2F&rct=j&q=htmltidy&ei=n49tTbCtGMjJcdz41cwF&usg=AFQjCNGgDAlawUTdfUIAI35wbZDCNRHaig&cad=rja) to help you.

Comment: I get what you are saying, but I'm a little confused because I was actually able to get my above code working.  I have a type-o somewhere else in the code.  Is there a reason this would work the way I described above, or do you think its a fluke?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: During my test on those stuff, the onLoadResource() or shouldOverrideUrlLoading() only works when user 'click' on some links. But if your content is requesting something else, e.g. you load a html page, and the page contains other images, the request on those images will not trigger.

Comment: do you know of any decent tutorials on your first suggested method?  Thanks.

Comment: I actually found this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065312/detect-click-on-html-button-through-javascript-in-android-webview -- which is what I need.