# How to save a authenticated webpage for offline using webview?

Tags: android, webview

I have a webview that displaying authenticated web page.

I need to save the content of the page for offline use.
Or even I need to get the Html content of the URL that is already authenticated through webview.

Is it possible?

I can't able to get the URL contents through HttpRequest, as the server expects authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the way to save webview contents offline.

I have implemented addJavascriptInterface() to the webview and got the full page contents thought a javascript call that return all the contents of current page's  element.

Please refer this for further details: 
[Android- using addJavaScriptInterface to return a value from Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5314492/1187469)