# How to handle webview click event in android studio?

Tags: android, webview

I am using webview in my application to show canvas. On my webview there is click here button. I want to open new activity on click of this 'click here' button on webview. I dont know how to handle this click event.Need help as soon as possible.

Following is my webview class code:

```
public class TableWebView extends Activity {

    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private String customer_id,hotel_id;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_table_web_view);
        WebView wvtable= (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webViewTable);
        wvtable.setWebViewClient(new MyViewClient());
        WebSettings webSettings = wvtable.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        customer_id = sharedPreferences.getString("cust_id", "0");//if no customerid found automatically 0 will be used
        hotel_id=sharedPreferences.getString("hotel_master_id","0");

        wvtable.loadUrl("http://192.168.100.169/zoilo_admin/public/index.php/show-hotel-view?hotel_id="+hotel_id+"&customer_id="+customer_id+"&date_time="+ Util.selected_date_time);



    }
```

And here is how it looks after opening that url in webview:

[image: table view]

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20917235/webviews-html-button-click-detection-in-activityjava-code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Binding JavaScript code to Android code

When developing a web application that's designed specifically for the WebView in your Android application, you can create interfaces between your JavaScript code and client-side Android code. For example, your JavaScript code can call a method in your Android code to start activity.

To bind a new interface between your JavaScript and Android code, call addJavascriptInterface(), passing it a class instance to bind to your JavaScript and an interface name that your JavaScript can call to access the class.

Caution: If you've set your targetSdkVersion to 17 or higher, you must add the @JavascriptInterface annotation to any method that you want available to your JavaScript (the method must also be public). If you do not provide the annotation, the method is not accessible by your web page when running on Android 4.2 or higher.

```
public class TableWebView extends Activity {

    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private String customer_id,hotel_id;
    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_table_web_view);

        WebView wvtable= (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webViewTable);

        wvtable.setWebViewClient(new MyViewClient());

        wvtable.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");

        WebSettings webSettings = wvtable.getSettings();

        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        customer_id = sharedPreferences.getString("cust_id", "0");//if no customerid found automatically 0 will be used
        hotel_id=sharedPreferences.getString("hotel_master_id","0");

        wvtable.loadUrl("http://192.168.100.169/zoilo_admin/public/index.php/show-hotel-view?hotel_id="+hotel_id+"&customer_id="+customer_id+"&date_time="+ Util.selected_date_time);
}



public class WebAppInterface { 
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */ 
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    } 

    /** Show a toast from the web page */ 
    @JavascriptInterface 
    public void startNewActivity() {
        //startActivity(new Intent(this, youactivityname.class));
    } 
}
```

This creates an interface called Android for JavaScript running in the WebView. At this point, your web application has access to the WebAppInterface class. For example, here's some HTML and JavaScript that call your "startNewActivity" method of your class using the new interface when the user clicks a button:

```
<input type="button" value="Click Here" onClick="showActivity()" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showActivity() {
        Android.startNewActivity();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: In your html or php page. that you try to load in web view  wvtable.loadUrl("http://192.168.100.169/zoilo_admin/public/index.php/show-hotel-view?hotel_id="+hotel_id+"&customer_id="+customer_id+"&date_time="+ Util.selected_date_time);

Comment: is it like php page will execute my startnewActivity function in android?

Comment: Yes It will call you native function.

Comment: But make sure you web page should come with  javascript block

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74410/discussion-between-dhiraj-devkar-and-bhavdip-pathar).