# Android : Touch event from dropdown menu within url loaded via webview

Tags: android, android-webview, html-select, touch-event

I have a webview in my activity which loads a url. The url has a dropdown menu within it (created using "select").

I want to receive the touch events which occur when I touch on the webview. I am able to get the touch event from the webview but when I touch the dropdown menu in the webview, the touch event is not received by the activity.

How can I get the touch events from dropdown menu within a url inside a webview ?

Here is what I have tried till now :-

```
            webView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
            {


                if (ActionType == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN  || ActionType == MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL) {

                    Log.d("WebView","Webview Touched");

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the android documentation here. 
http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Also check this link to see some examples. [Webview's Html button click detection in Activity(java code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20917235/webviews-html-button-click-detection-in-activityjava-code)