# Is there anyway to extract file from link?

Tags: android

I have been writing a downloader which is working fine on links that has extensions in them. e.g.

```
http://speedtest.ftp.otenet.gr/files/test100Mb.db
```

but it doesn't work with this link:

```
https://dl.apkmos.com/?dl=423b122b186bac91faf269d8432d393c
```

How can I extract a downloadable link from the above mentioned URL?

Comment: It is hard to imagine what you did so that it is not working. It is as simple as issuing a GET request to the URL and store the result.

Comment: actually i have been using 
https://github.com/tonyofrancis/Fetch to download files but it doesnt allow to download from indirect links. I am trying to find ways to get file path from indirect link.

Comment: you need the get the link form webview on button click,,,refer this https://medium.com/@kpbird/android-webview-detect-html-element-on-click-263431c52e01

Comment: thanks for you reply, let me check :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(final WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        view.addJavascriptInterface(new Object()
        {
            @JavascriptInterface
            public void performClick() throws Exception
            {
                view.getUrl();  // here you can get apk download urls
                Log.d("LOGIN::", "Clicked");
              //  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }, "login");
        return true;
    }
}
```

[Webview's Html button click detection in Activity(java code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20917235/webviews-html-button-click-detection-in-activityjava-code)

Comment: thanks for you answer, i am getting url from web-view but how can i identify if user opens a link in firefox or chrome?

Comment: @Zubair Rehman it's not  a matter on which browser user opening....if you can able to get the link so you can able to donwload file using asyntask or downloadmanager

Comment: right, how can i plug this code with firefox or chrome browsers in android phone? could you please elaborate?