# How to detect button click on HTML page

Tags: android, android-webview

can anybody tell me how to detect click events on html page
i have one android app. in that app i have loaded one thrid party website.
in that website some print buttons are there.But when i touch print button 
nothing is happened. So i just want to know that how can detect the button click 
on webpage and execute printjob

here is my main activity

```
package com.example.re;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public WebView webView;

    private WebView mWebView;





    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new overload());
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onReceivedSslError(final WebView view, final SslErrorHandler handler, final SslError error) {
                handler.proceed();
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favion){
                super.onPageStarted(view,url,favion);

            }
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(final WebView view, String url) {

                //show webview
                findViewById(R.id.web).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);




            }
        });
        webView.loadUrl(url);
        // webView.loadUrl("https://192.168.0.186:8443/");//wifi
        // webView.loadUrl("https://192.168.1.6:8443/");//Ethernet
        webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        }
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setLongClickable(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);




   }


    public class overload extends WebViewClient{
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }


    /**--------------------------------------------print--------------------------------------------------**/
    private void doWebViewPrint() {
    // Create a WebView object specifically for printing
    WebView webView = new WebView(MainActivity.this);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    Log.i(TAG, "page finished loading " + url);
    createWebPrintJob(view);
    mWebView = null;
    }
    });

    // Generate an HTML document on the fly:
    String htmlDocument = "<html><body><h1>Test Content</h1><p>Testing, " +
    "testing, testing...</p></body></html>";
    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmlDocument, "text/HTML", "UTF-8", null);

    // Keep a reference to WebView object until you pass the PrintDocumentAdapter
    // to the PrintManager
    mWebView = webView;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void createWebPrintJob(WebView webView) {

        // Get a PrintManager instance
        PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) MainActivity.this
                .getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);

        String jobName = getString(R.string.app_name) + " Document";

        // Get a print adapter instance
        PrintDocumentAdapter printAdapter = webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter(jobName);

        // Create a print job with name and adapter instance
        PrintJob printJob = printManager.print(jobName, printAdapter,
                new PrintAttributes.Builder().build());

        // Save the job object for later status checking

        ArrayList<PrintJob> printJobs = new ArrayList<PrintJob>();

        printJobs.add(printJob);
    }

    /**--------------------------------------------print--------------------------------------------------**/






    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        if (webView.canGoBack()){webView.goBack();}
        else{

            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this, R.style.AlertDialogStyle)
                    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            MainActivity.this.finish();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                    .show();
            // super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20917235/webviews-html-button-click-detection-in-activityjava-code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webview's Html button click detection in Activity(java code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20917235/webviews-html-button-click-detection-in-activityjava-code)

Comment: Do you control the source code of the HTML Page?