# Redirecting from webview to the android app

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I am working on an android app that is having a webview in it that holds a button in it.Now what I want to do is that whenever I click on that button instead of remain in the webview I should be redirected to the homepage of my android app.What should I do.

Comment: show me your code here.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20917235/webviews-html-button-click-detection-in-activityjava-code.

Answer (score 0):

You bind the WebView to your Android application with the JavascriptInterface. Here are some reference docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview#BindingJavaScript[Communicationwith web-view and activity/fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview#BindingJavaScript)