# How to finish the activity when user clicks on the submit button on webView

Tags: java, android, android-webview, android-websettings

I have a webview in my activity and i am displaying a form in this webview. I want to finish the activity when user clicks on the Submit button of the form. How can i do this.

Or in Another way you can say that i want to get the id of the button when users click on that in java and perform the finish Activity method.

I have gone through this link

[Detect click on HTML button through javascript in Android WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065312/detect-click-on-html-button-through-javascript-in-android-webview)

Thank for considering..

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the parameter into java script handler method to solve ur second option.

```
    <button type="button" onclick="jshandler.onClick('HEllo');">OK</button>
```

And retrieve from the method.

```
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void onClick(String id) {
        Log.i("JsHandler onClick", id);
    }
```

u can find the complete tutorial [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/r2xfcvfbknbvqp2/EJ3v2oF4yN/testing)

Comment: can u see the log message?

Comment: Unfortunately I can see the log in my log cat. :)

Comment: pls see the updated answer. This tutorial may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html)'s methods. Some of them might be appropriate for you. For example if the submit button loads another page and you know it's url, you can listen for it's loading in [onPageStarted](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageStarted%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String,%20android.graphics.Bitmap%29) or [onPageFinished](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageFinished%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29). I am not sure whether these methods will work for you but at least you can search for WebViewClient solutions of a similar problem.