# android detect image click inside webview?

Tags: android, webview

i want to detect `<img` click inside `webview` ? if so how ? i need an example plz

so far as i know i can detect `<a href` click inside `webview` by useing `WebViewClient`

but i need to detect `<img` click without using java script can i ?

this is my code :

```
WebView webview = ( WebView ) findViewById(R.id.wv);

WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
settings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true); 


String summary = "<html><body>You scored <fieldset><legend>adfadf</legend>"
                    + " <a href='http://192.168.1.100/1.jpg'><img src='http://192.168.1.100/1.jpg' /></a> </fieldset> "
                    + " <b>192</b> points.</body></html>";


webview.loadData(summary, "text/html", null);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer this answer,

[Detect click on HTML button through javascript in Android WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065312/detect-click-on-html-button-through-javascript-in-android-webview)

Same procedure track image click as well. If it doesn't work, create a button in HTML and place the image as background for the button, so you can track the button using answer given in the link.

Thanks.

Comment: if i have multi images inside webview how i can catch them all ! that is the point

Comment: Send a parameter(like ID) in function you give onclick attribute, so you can identify which image is being clicked.