# Click ImageView in WebView android

Tags: android, webview

In my Webview I have many tag img(ImageView) and I want get event when click tag img in webview to show position of it in many image. How i do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android detect image click inside webview?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21409369/android-detect-image-click-inside-webview)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to enable javascript. like this,

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

then bind your javascript code with android code,

```
public class WebAppInterface {
Context mContext;

/** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
WebAppInterface(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
   }

/** Show a toast from the web page */
@JavascriptInterface
public void showToast(String toast) {
    Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
}
```

then add javascriptInterface Method with webview, It will call your android method from any javascript method,

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
```

After that in your webview page just add onclick method on each tag img, and call javascript method from onclick event,

```
<img src="YOUR IMAGE SOURCE" id="your img positon OR anything" onClick="showAndroidToast(this.id)" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function showAndroidToast(toast) {
    Android.showToast(toast);
}
</script>
```

for more reference please refer [Android Webview](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)

Comment: thank you I will try it.
It mean with each tag img I must add string id = position and onclick = showAndroidToast (this.id)

Comment: yes in id you can use whatever you want to use for further processing.

Comment: how I do to get position of img tag in webview? Ex my web have 5 tag img and I want when click tag img3 it show toast 3

Comment: just put id of your img tag to 3. as id="3".

Comment: sorry to bother after a while, but how I can show src of imageview?

Answer (score 1):

What I understand is that you need to find out when an image in the webview is clicked.

If so, you can use this :
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#getHitTestResult()

and this :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.HitTestResult.html

use it in your click listener and it should work!

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Javascript Interface` to bind Javascript code (from html) to Android code.

eg:

**JavascriptInterface**:

```
public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**HTML (JS)**:

```
<input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showAndroidToast(toast) {
        Android.showToast(toast);
    }
</script>
```

Add the JavaScriptInterface to your `WebView`:

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
```

[This](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) is an example from the official documentation.

And this is [another tutorial](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-bind-javascript-code-to-android-code/).