# Handle onclick function of html webview in android

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

I'm trying to handled onclick of html in android.refered [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065312/detect-click-on-html-button-through-javascript-in-android-webview/4075955#4075955) but its not detecting.

```
<script language="javascript">

   function GreenClicked()
   {
      valid.performClick();
      document.getElementById("Green").value = "J'accepte";
   }
</script>
```

html tag inside body-

```
 <div  id="Green" onclick="GreenClicked()">Green<span></span></div>
```

java code -

```
mGreenPassenger= new Button(getActivity());
        mGreenPassenger.setOnClickListener(this);

        WebSettings ws = mWebView.getSettings();
        ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        // Add the interface to record javascript events
        mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(mGreenPassenger, "Green");
```

Comment: use onclick="GreenClicked()"

Comment: changed it.still not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pitfalls of copying code from StackOverflow is that you might not understand it fully.

```
function GreenClicked()
{
    Green.performClick(); // Needs to be your JS Interface name
    document.getElementById("Green").value = "J'accepte";
}
```

The [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript) on this are great. Use them. You'll have more of an understanding of what's going on in your own code.