# Html Button OnClick to move Another Activity in Android

Tags: android, android-webview

I am getting `None of the methods in the added interface @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface.They will not be visible in Api level 17.` compile error at addJavascriptInterface method.

I have pointed out the error line in below code:

**WebView code:**

```
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;

webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.load_url);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

 if (new File(url).exists()) {
            webView.loadUrl(FILENAME_PREFIX + url);
            Log.d("fileurl", "" + FILENAME_PREFIX + url);

        }

        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new Object() { --->None of the methods in the added interface @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface.They will not be visible in Api level 17.

            @JavascriptInterface
            public void performClick() {
                Intent intRef=new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intRef);
            }
        }, "ok");
```

**Html Code:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>

         <div>
            <button type="button" onclick="ok.performClick();">OK</button>
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am using  minSdkVersion 11 and targetSdkVersion 22.I had called   @JavascriptInterface in before method.You could see that in above code.

Anyone can help me with this.Thank you.

Comment: refer this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25420581/handle-onclick-function-of-html-webview-in-android

Comment: Read this http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Html Page:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript">

        function moveToScreenTwo() {
        Android.moveToNextScreen();
        }
        </script>

    </head>

  <body>
     <div>
            <input type="button" value="Locate" onClick="moveToScreenTwo()" />
        </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

**FirstACtivity.java:**

```
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;

webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.load_url);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

 if (new File(url).exists()) {
            webView.loadUrl(FILENAME_PREFIX + url);
            Log.d("fileurl", "" + FILENAME_PREFIX + url);
  webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
        }
  //Class to be injected in Web page
    public class WebAppInterface {
        Context mContext;

        /**
         * Instantiate the interface and set the context
         */
        WebAppInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void moveToNextScreen() {

            Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
     }
```

For more Reference: Check [this tutorial](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/binding-javascript-and-android-code-example/).

Answer (score 2):

From the Android 4.2 documentation:

> Caution: If you've set your targetSdkVersion to 17 or higher, you
>   must add the @JavascriptInterface annotation to any method that you
>   want available your web page code (the method must also be public). If
>   you do not provide the annotation, then the method will not accessible
>   by your web page when running on Android 4.2 or higher.

You will have to annotate each method with @JavascriptInterface within your class that you'd like to access from Javascript.

**EDIT:**
I have implemented this way in my code:

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "ok");
public class WebAppInterface {
        Context mContext;

        /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
        WebAppInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void performClick() {
            Intent intRef=new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intRef);
        }
    }
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: it would be suitable for that only one method,that I had pointed out.