# Android. Webview. How to make element unclickable?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

WebView is loading data from [url](http://develop.gio.uz/index.php/o-nas-mobile).

```
wvBrowser.loadUrl(MainActivity.URL_ABOUT);
```

On WebViewClient's onPageStarted method I am trying to use javascript:

```
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        String javascript = "javascript: "
                + "document.getElementById('logo').setAttribute(\"style\",\"pointer-events: none ;\");";
        view.loadUrl(javascript);
    }
```

Result: element is still clickable.

How to make only one element unclickable?

Answer (score 1):

```
webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
       return true; //True if the listener has consumed the event, false otherwise. 
    }  
});
```

It will disable the webview touch event

```
webView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
webView.setFocusable(false);
```

It will make the links non-focusable.

Check this for more customization using javascript in android

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4075955/3020568

Comment: what if i want to make only one element(logo) unclickable?