# assign onClickListener for WebView html views

Tags: android, html, view, webview, onclick

I have a `WebView` contains some **html code**, this html code is a code that displays five buttons created through it, I want to listen to the `onClick` or `onTouch` action of these buttons so that when the user clicks on it some action happens, all I want to know is how to assign `onClick` for these views which is created by html, and for sure the `onClick` process can be added to buttons through the html code itself so it will OK also if there is a way to assign an `onClick` regarding to html code.

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065312/detect-click-on-html-button-through-javascript-in-android-webview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add listener for html's buttons in android code. Instead, you can use Javascript Interface with Webview.

```
public final class MyJSInterface
{
    public void button1function(){
        //do something
    }
}
```

Write all functions in this Interface.

Add that JSInterface to your webview.

```
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJSInterface(), "MyJSInterface");  //name you want that will be used in javascript file.
```

Now in your html's javascript, you can call these functions using JavaScriptInterface name:

```
function method1() {
    MyJSInterface.button1function();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: great, that's all I wanted to know

Answer (score 1):

You need to write JavaScript for HTML button click listeners.

```
<button type="button" id="exit" onclick="exitButtonClick();">Exit</button>

<script language="javascript">

   function exitButtonClick()
   {
      // Do Something
   }

</script>
```

If you want to call native java code from HTML's buttons then you need to add JavaScriptInterface to your WebView. For details please check below link

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Comment: thanks for that illustration, giving an overview of html code is a good tip