# Returning to App from Webview on logout of web application

Tags: java, android, methods, webview

I have pasted a small snippet of my code that will allow the person to click on the `webview` and return back to my login app. The web application in `webview` should only do this if they click the logout inside the web application that *runs in* the `webview`. In other words it shouldn't return to the login app just because they clicked somewhere in the webview.

I have tried doing this using the `onPageStarted` and just can't get it to work. It ask for 3 parameters and `Android Studio` won't even compile it. It may be the way I'm trying to call it as I don't quite understand how to call that method, after reading the documentation.

Also, I tried to make a private class called `myWebClient` to call the `onPageStarted` but can't seem to call that one either correctly in my `MainActivity`.

Here's the working code that will take me back to my app on ANY click within the webview.

```
webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        String checkurl;

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class); 
        startActivity(intent); 
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), checkurl, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return false;
        }

        });
```

Here's what I tried which didn't work.

```
webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            String checkurl;
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
                public void onPageStarted( WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon){
                    if (checkurl == "mylogoutURLgoes here") {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class); 
                        startActivity(intent); 
                    }
                    super.onPageStarted(webView, url, favicon);
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), checkurl, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably this is what you are looking for:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        if ("myLogoutUrl".equals(url)){
            //do stuff
        }
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }
});
```

Another solution will be to add `Javascript` interface to communicate with code.

Comment: nikis - Thank you so much. That HELPED and solved my problem! Im really new to Java and having a hard time with calling the methods and classes I need correctly. I also didn't want to learn Javascript as one new language at time is all my brain can handle.

Comment: @Jay btw, you may want to take a look here http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Answer (score 0):

This post should lead you in the right direction. [Detect click on HTML button through javascript in Android WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065312/detect-click-on-html-button-through-javascript-in-android-webview)

You need to create buttons in Java and add javascript interface components in your web app to handle them.

Comment: Nic - thanks for the link and fast reply. Javascript is my next language to explore.