# Android Webview cant focus on its elements

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a android TV app and so all my controls are using the focus(remote).
I have a webview which loads up the url and displays the content. 
Now this page has a section in the centre and there are 2 buttons inside this section. 
Now the focus is on the section itself and it doesnt go inside and focus on the buttons.
If I click on up and down buttons on the remote, the page just scrolls up and down but the focus doesnt move inside to the buttons.
Any idea how I can solve this?
Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4075955/1318946

Comment: The webpage is from a third party so cant do anything on it. @PratikButani

Comment: The webpage is yours, but webview is not. So I wondering if calling `webView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);` will be of any help. As it will call focus to your webview only.

Comment: I tried that. It doesnt help. And webview mine. Webpage is not.

Comment: you want to setup focus on navigation buttons?

Comment: @ssh There are 2 buttons which are inside a section in the webview. the focus comes on the entire section but doesnt go a level deeper on the buttons

Comment: @Gaurav Did you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try something like this

```
mWebview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() { 
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) { 
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
                if (view.hasFocus() == false) { 
                    view.requestFocus(); 
                } 
                break; 
         } 
         return false; 
    }
});
```

Comment: This gives focus to the whole section and not the buttons which I want

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a wrapper on your webview, which holds navigation above on webview.

After that disable all user-actions to this webview.(touch,focus,etc..)

Setup buttons and redirect user actions to webview.

For ex.

UP button click -> redirect to scroll webview.