# How to catch when HTML element ist clicked in WebView with Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: html, xamarin.forms, webview

I'm using a Xamarin.Forms WebView to bind in a HTML webpage in my App. Now i need to execute some code within my App when a specific button in that HTML page ist clicked.

I have seen a few approaches for Android WebViews but i cant transfer it to Xamarin.Forms.

Example: [How to catch element click by ID in Android webview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32698709/how-to-catch-element-click-by-id-in-android-webview)

Comment: You can use the plugin FormsWebview, which allows the callback to c# code from javascript. You can intercept this callback and execute your logic then. Plugin: https://github.com/SKLn-Rad/Xam.Plugin.Webview

Comment: Based on your description, do you want to achieve a hybird webview in your application like this link? https://xamarinexplorer.com/2017/12/30/handle-button-click-event-xamarin-webview/ , If so, you should achieved by `custom renderer`

Comment: Lets say i have a WebView with google as contentpage. Now i want to write "This is a test" in Console when the search button is clicked. If someone could give me sample code for this simple example I will be able to transfer it to my usecase.

Comment: You can refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/45644422/10627299, he achieve it with `XLabs.Forms.Controls.HybridWebView`