# how to implement java onClick method in stringBuffer append html button

Tags: android

when user click on this button java method shown up

```
sb.append("<Button  type=\"submit\">Transfer</Button>");
```

this is my button clicklistener

```
  @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Check out this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065312/detect-click-on-html-button-through-javascript-in-android-webview

Comment: i am not using WebView